# The script app URL is different than web app URL

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to get the `Url` of the "current web app URL".

When I use the code:

```
function test(){
var $url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
Logger.log($url);
}
```

This shows the URL which is different than the URL I see after I click on "Publish->Deploy as web app->Current web app URL".

I tried looking in the documentation, but it seems like the code is correct.

Comment: Have you tried publishing a new version?

Comment: Yes, that fixed the URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to deploy the app with a new version so the project could update the code and configuration.