# How to correctly display the "Current web app URL" in spreadsheet with `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188274/the-script-app-url-is-different-than-web-app-url), but I still cannot get the correct url.

Furthermore, I keep getting a link that looks like this: `https://script.google.com/macros/s/<ID>/exec` but should be getting one that looks like this: `https://script.google.com/a/<DOMAIN>/macros/s/<ID>/exec`.

EDIT:
The first link seems to work only until I manually deploy as a web app. But I am approaching this as shown [in this GitHub repo](https://github.com/RomainVialard/programmatically-deploy-a-web-app). I want to be able to distribute the Spreadsheet and give whoever is using it the ability to deploy directly from a custom menu in the Spreadsheet.

I hope this isn't becoming a duplicate of [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893378/deploying-script-as-webapp-directly-from-sheets).

UPDATE:
Initially I was trying to display the URL by calling on a function (`appURL()`) from within a cell. But now I tried setting value for that cell directly from the script file as `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` and that helped getting the `<DOMAIN>` part, but I still don't get the exact same as shown in Publish>Deploy as web app>"Current web app URL:" (not the same `<ID>`) which for some reason doesn't work.

Comment: Both links are correct. Why do you need the URL including `/a/<DOMAIN>/`?

Comment: @Rubén, the "Current web app URL" includes it, and when I open both in my browser to test, it's the only URL that seems to work.

Comment: That is because you are using a G Suite account. What if you instead use a Google common account (i.e. username@gmail.com)?

Comment: @Rubén, but I HAVE to use a G Suite account. Is there no way at all to get the exact URL as sheen when Publish>Deploy as web app>"Current web app URL:"?

Comment: Did you try building the final link yourself using the deployment url and the strings "a/" & "<DOMAIN>/" in their respective parts of the url? Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: Thank @Aerials. I just figured that part out (see my UPDATE). What I seem to be missing now is the <ID> part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could build it, if you know the domain name.

#### Example:

```js
function createDomainURL(domain, deploymentUrl){
    var url = deploymentUrl.split('/');
    url.splice(3,0,'a');
    url.splice(5,0,domain);
    return url.join('/');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like we posted at the same time. But I already figured this part out (see my UPDATE). What I am missing now is the correct ID